# Using controller inside another controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, binding, controller, angularjs-controller, angularjs-controlleras

Why I can't bind to controller's variable inside second controller?

```
<div ng-app="ManagerApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        Main: 
        <div ng-repeat="state in states">
            {{state}}
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="InsideCtrl as inside">
            Inside:
            <div ng-repeat="state in inside.states2">
                {{state}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

var angularApp = angular.module('ManagerApp', []);

angularApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.states = ["NY", "CA", "WA"];
}]);

angularApp.controller('InsideCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.states2 = ["NY", "CA", "WA"];
}]);
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/nukRe/135/

Second ng-repeat doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you are using `controllerAs` you should be using `this` keyword in controller

```
angularApp.controller('InsideCtrl', [ function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.states2 = ["NY", "CA", "WA"];
}]);
```

[**Forked Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/nukRe/136/)

**NOTE**

> Technically you should follow one approach at a time. Don't mix up
>   this two pattern together, Either use `controllerAs` syntax/ Normal
>   controller declaration as you did for `MainCtrl` using `$scope`

Comment: Should someone stumble across this answer, it is correct, but apparently only starting with Angular 1.2.1. The OP fiddle has Angular 1.1.1 selected, and Pankaj has it set to 1.2.1.  Took me 15 minutes of "why is this change not working" to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

> as inside

from here:

`<div ng-controller="InsideCtrl as inside">`
such that:

```
`<div ng-controller="InsideCtrl">`
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<div ng-app="ManagerApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        Main: 
        <div ng-repeat="state in states">
            {{state}}
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="InsideCtrl">
            Inside:
            <div ng-repeat="state in states2">
                {{state}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain *why* this works, right now it's a substandard answer.